# Matrix norm square properties.

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove one of these inequalities. This isn't a homework problem but trying to solve out of curiosity as it didn't have any relationship between $x$ and $\alpha$.

How do you prove:
$$\alpha * ||x||^2 \leq ||Ax||^2 \leq \beta*||x||^2$$
where
$$0 \leq \alpha\leq  \beta$$
A is a matrix and $x$ is a real vector.

Comment: Any hint will also be helpful.Not necessarily the answer.

Comment: Hint: It wouldn't be true if you required $0 < \alpha$.

Comment: Thanks @RobertIsrael. You mean to say it's true when alpha is 0?

Comment: As I commented in response to 5xum's answer, you need quantifiers.  My guess is that the statement is "For every $A$ there exist $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that for all $x$, ...".  With $\alpha = 0$ the first inequality is true, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove the statement with just what you have, as it is simply not true. If $A=I$ (the identity matrix) and $\alpha = 2$, then it is clear that if $x\neq 0$, $$\alpha ||x||^2 =2||x||^2>||x||^2=||Ax||^2$$

Comment: Obviously you can't take just any $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Quantifiers are important!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well, the way the question is stated at the moment, there are no quantifiers, so the answer cannot be given.